# ArrayList with two methods in java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have an `arraylist` in java and 2 methods for it. I want to use these two methods for my arraylist at once.

In the first method, I have used the method `remove()`, so the arraylist doesn't have all of its elements anymore.

For the second method, I also need to have **the arraylist with all of its elements**. But the Arraylist is not the same anymore.

I am thinking about **multithreading in java**. Is there another way to solve this problem?

**Here is my code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Adding items to arrayList
    list.add("aaa");
    list.add("bbb");
    list.add("ccc");
    list.add("ddd");
    System.out.println("The arraylist contains the following elements: " + list);

    method1(list);
    method2(list);
}

public static void method1(List<String> list) {

    for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String s = iterator.next();
        if (!s.startsWith("a")) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List1: " + list);
}

public static void method2(List<String> changedFilesList) {

    for (Iterator<String> iterator = changedFilesList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String s = iterator.next();
        if (!s.startsWith("b")) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List2:" + changedFilesList);
```

**Output:**

```
The arraylist contains the following elements: [aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
List of the other: [aaa]
List of the other: []
```

**Expected Output:**

```
The arraylist contains the following elements: [aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
List of the other: [aaa]
List of the other: [bbb]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem but it looks like you want a copy of the list or maybe even an empty list for the first method (btw it looks like `remove()` should remove all elements in which case the name `clear()` or `removeAll()` would be better suited).

Comment: Post the code you have so far, and do read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you @Thomas , I have arealdy edited my question.

Comment: Thank you @JaggenSWE , I have already edited my question.

Comment: So what you really need are copies of the list as you also can see in the answers given. An additional information for your learning experience: multithreading is _not_ a way to solve your issue. Without any measures taken that effectively create copies of the list simultaneous operations would operate on the _same_ instance of the list and thus might mess up things even more (with somewhat unpredictable results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two methods look too much alike, you should combine them in to one. Also, how about looking at it a different way? In stead of removing stuff from the list, add them to another.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("aaa");
    list.add("bbb");
    list.add("ccc");
    list.add("ddd");
    System.out.println("The arraylist contains the following elements: " + list);

    System.out.printLn("List 1: " + method(list, "a"));
    System.out.printLn("List 2: " + method(list, "b"));
}

private List<String> method(List<String> list, String filter) {
    List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : list) {
        if (s.startsWith(filter)) {
            filteredList.add(s);
        }
    }

    return filteredList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This way is even better! @numsu

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark the best answer as the correct one for your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the list before calling the first method:

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList(list);
```

Then, call `method1` with `list` and `method2` with `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public static void method1(List<String> list) {  
        List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.addAll(list);
        for (Iterator<String> iterator=list1.iterator();iterator.hasNext();{
            String s = iterator.next();
            if (!s.startsWith("a")) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
       }
       System.out.println("List1: " + list1);
    }

    public static void method2(List<String> changedFilesList) {
        List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.addAll(changedFilesList);
        for (Iterator<String> iterator=list1.iterator();iterator.hasNext();{
            String s = iterator.next();
            if (!s.startsWith("b")) {
            iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("List2:" + list1);
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works!

Comment: Instead of just feeding code you might want to consider adding a few explanatory words. After all people should learn the concepts behind a solution and not just how to copy-paste.

Comment: For efficiency reasons I'd prefer `new ArrayList<String>(list)` instead of creating a new list and then calling `addAll()`. That way the array list is already initialized with a correctly sized internal array.

Comment: I am new to Java, so I just want to know more about ArrayList etc. <br> I would like to experiment different methods for an arraylist. for example: if you have a list of your clients and you want sort the list depending on some specific attributes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

- As **ArrayList** implements **Cloneable** you can use the following before calling **method2()**:

  ```
  final List<String> copy = (List) list.clone();
  ```
- Call **method2()** as follows:

  ```
  method2(copy);
  ```

Comment: thank you, it is useful.